What integral transform is being used in this case?
I'm trying to understand a lecture where they compute the integral of $\frac{1}{|\vec x - \vec A|}$ for fixed A and integrating over all $x\in R^3$.
I'm specifically confused by the final line in this slide where they use an integral transform to convert the said integrand into a separable form. Full lecture included here.
In this line $r_C = |\vec x - \vec A|$

